# Assign value to std::string pointer created with soap_malloc

Tags: c++, std, gsoap

I am currently implementing a webservice using gsoap version 2.8 and running into segmentation faults.

Therefor I allocate memory using soap_malloc like this:

```
OSoap *myObject = (OSoap *)soap_new_OSoap(this);
myObject->myString = (std::string*)soap_malloc(this, sizeof(std::string));
```

The source code of OSoap is generated using a wsdl and looks like this:

```
class SOAP_CMAC OSoap {
...
public:
   std::string *myString; // optional attribute
...
}
```

Now i have a string allocated but how do I write content to this string?

```
myObject->myString->insert(0, "123");
```

and

```
*(myObject->myString) += "abc";
```

lead to segmentation faults.

```
std::string *abc = new std::string("abc");
myObject->myString = abc;
```

works but produces a memory leak which i try to avoid.

Searching google or stackoverflow for how to copy a string in c++ did not give me a hint how to solve the problem using std::string pointers

Comment: I don't know gSoap, but it occurs to me that you are assigning the std::string (in a fixed memory allocation) and then inserting/appending to the internal memory of the string. When you new the string you are in complete control of the object and it works (but leaks) - could yo experiment with fixed size char arrays and see if soap_malloc woks then ? (I.E. copy into the array)

Comment: fixed size char array did not work, because I would need to instanciate them with {}, char* did work.

Comment: ok - I think it is possible that the seg fault is due to the string reallocating memory internally. Hopefully this will get you a bit further on. Sorry I can't be more help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok - when using std::string* one should use `soap_instantiate_std__string` instead of `soap_malloc` which I did not find in the documentation, then everything works fine!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I saw that your std::string* is an "optional" attribute.
After i wrote :

```
<xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="myString" type="xsd:string"/>
```

it changed to a std::string in header !
I don't know if you use a xsd element but thats a way which works good.

Comment: In my case it was not allowed to change the xsd!

Answer (score 0):

Complex types can be instantiating by using `soap_new_XXX` functions, like `soap_new_std__string(soap, 1)` in this case. This function calls `soap_instantiate_std__string` internally. Memory will be automatically released by gsoap.

See [gsoap documentation](https://www.genivia.com/doc/soapdoc2.html) chapter 9.13.1  Memory Allocation and Management Policies.